# How to make directories according to an output of a program and copy files in to them

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to do the following,
Verify.exe crawls a directory structure and checks files one by one for any defects. File is passed to verify.exe as a command line argument. If any defects are found in a file it prints an error code (one line string). If file is legitimate nothing is printed.  I want to create a folder for each error code and copy the faulty file to the folder so I can take a look at it. If file has no errors nothing is done.

Files need to be checked are in D:\Test\docs\r1 - For testing purpose I have only one file in D:\Test\docs\r1.

```
::@echo off
CD D:\Test\doc\r1\
FOR /R %%a IN (*) DO (
 ECHO %%a
 FOR /F %%b IN ('D:\Test\doc\Verify.exe /i:"%%a"') do SET MyVAR=%%b
 IF NOT "%MyVAR%" == "" (
  ECHO "IF one"
  IF EXIST D:\Test\doc\%MyVAR% (
  ECHO "IF two"
  MD D:\Test\doc\%MyVAR%
  )
  COPY %%a D:\Test\doc\%MyVAR%
 )
 SET MyVAR=
 ECHO "------------------------"
)
```

I get the following echo on the command line.

```
D:\Test\doc>CD D:\Test\doc\r1\

D:\Test\doc\r1>FOR /R %a IN (*) DO (
ECHO %a
 FOR /F %b IN ('D:\Test\doc\Verify.exe /i:"%a"') do SET MyVAR=%b
 IF NOT "" == "" (
ECHO "IF one"
 IF EXIST D:\Test\doc\ (
ECHO "IF two"
 MD D:\Test\doc\
)
 COPY %a D:\Test\doc\
)
 SET MyVAR=
 ECHO "------------------------"
)

D:\Test\doc\r1>(
ECHO D:\Test\doc\r1\A5 Incident Management.doc
 FOR /F %b IN ('D:\Test\doc\Verify.exe /i:"D:\Test\doc\r1\A5 Incident Management.doc"') do SET MyVAR=%b
 IF NOT "" == "" (
ECHO "IF one"
 IF EXIST D:\Test\doc\ (
ECHO "IF two"
 MD D:\Test\doc\
)
 COPY D:\Test\doc\r1\A5 Incident Management.doc D:\Test\doc\
)
 SET MyVAR=
 ECHO "------------------------"
)
D:\Test\doc\r1\A5 Incident Management.doc

D:\Test\doc\r1>SET MyVAR=0x8004170b
"------------------------"
D:\Test\doc\r1>
```

Could someone help me in following issues..

- The loop has run three times
- No folders are created
- It seems there is an issue in assigning exe command line output to MyVar

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the output of your `verify.exe` command is correct, you probably should **enable delayed expansion** (at the top of your batch file):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

and use the `!` syntax for variable used within a loop (replace `%MYVAR%` with `!MYVAR!`)

Otherwise, within the for-loop, `%MYVAR%` is only evaluated before the first run (where no value is defined).